# Enabling CORS with openapi-generator

Tags: reactjs, flask, openapi-generator, connexion

So I'm using [openapi-generator](https://openapi-generator.tech/) to generate a flask server to serve my api.

I am having no trouble generating the server running it and viewing endpoints in my browser. However I get a CORS error when I make a GET request from my React Web App.

I've tried a few things to enable CORS.

I tried adding the header to my endpoint in my .yaml.

```
/pipelines:
    get:
      summary: 'Returns a list of pipelines.'
      operationId: get_pipelines
      responses:
        '200':
          description: 'A JSON array of pipelines'
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/Pipeline'
          headers:
            Access-Control-Allow-Origin: '*'
        default:
          description: Unexpected error
          content:
            'application/json':
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/ErrorMessage'
```

When I try adding the header via the .yaml and try to regenerate the server module, I get this error:

```
-attribute paths.'/pipelines'(get).responses.200.Access-Control-Allow-Origin is not of type `object
```

I also tried installing and importing flask_cors in the **main**.py of the server module.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import connexion

from openapi_server import encoder
from flask_cors import CORS

def main():
    app = connexion.App(__name__, specification_dir='./openapi/')
    CORS(app.app)
    app.app.json_encoder = encoder.JSONEncoder
    app.add_api('openapi.yaml',
                arguments={'title': 'ICDR API'},
                pythonic_params=True)
    app.run(port=5050)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And I tried both those together. These fixes I found in the swagger-codegen [petstore.yaml](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/openapitools/openapi-generator/master/modules/openapi-generator/src/test/resources/2_0/petstore.yaml) example and in the [connexion docs](https://connexion.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cookbook.html#cors-support).

However as I stated I'm using openapi-generator so its a little different than either of those other tools, but I'm having a lot of trouble finding any information on how to set this up correctly. Has anyone worked with openapi-generator before who can help me out?

Comment: Did you try to provide the actual link rather than a wildcard? 
`headers:Access-Control-Allow-Origin: 'http://localhost:3000/'`
This worked for me when I tried it in C#

Comment: Yeah thats what I did first and I got the same error when I try to generate the server.


`-attribute paths.'/pipelines'(get).responses.200.Access-Control-Allow-Origin is not of type 'object'`

Comment: Add the logger to flask cors `logging.getLogger('flask_cors').level = logging.DEBUG` then you can check the problem. Move the `CORS(app.app)` for after `app.run(port=5050)`

Comment: I will give this a shot I have currently moved on to another more pressing issue, but as soon as I get back to this I will let you know how it goes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OpenApi code generator uses the [connexion](https://connexion.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) library under the hood, in their documentation they propose using flask_cors see: [here](https://connexion.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cookbook.html#cors-support)

I am currently using custom mustache templates forked from the originals, so in the `\__main__.mustache` I added the lines

```
from flask_cors import CORS
....
CORS(app.app)
app.run(port=.....)
```

make sure to install `flask_cors`  or add it to your requirements.txt

P.S. you can specify the template location with `generate ... -t TEMPALTE/FOLDER?LOCATION`

Comment: My team and I ended up figuring this out around the time I asked this question, but this is the correct answer, so I figured I'd give you the credit!